# Codeigniter - undefined variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I am getting this error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: results

Filename: views/body.php

Line Number: 75

My Model

```
function get_results($search_term='default')
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('books');
    $this->db->like('title', $search_term);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

My Controller

```
function execute_search(){


    $this->load->model('books_model');
    $search_term = $this->input->post('search');

    $data['results'] = $this->books_model->get_results($search_term);

   $this->load->view('body', $data);


}
```

My View

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<div>
<?php
if(is_array($results)) : foreach ($results as $val) : ?>

    <ul>
    <li><?php echo $val['title'] ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<h2> No books found </h2>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

I do not understand because I have called the variable 'results' in my controller yet it is not working in the view. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Because your model does not returns any data..try print_r($query->result_array()) in ur model..is it showing any data

Answer (score 0):

Try not returning the query result as an array until the for loop.

Your Model:

```
function get_results($search_term='default')
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('books');
    $this->db->like('title', $search_term);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

No changes in your Controller

Your View

```
<h1>Search Results</h1>
<div>
<?php
foreach ($results->result_array() as $val) : ?>

    <ul>
    <li><?php echo $val['title'] ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php else : ?>

<h2> No books found </h2>

<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```